# Nested recursion theorem (problem 5.21, "Notes on set theory", Y. Moschovakis)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

I found this problem in the book "Notes on set theory" by Yiannis Moschovakis; it's the x5.21 from the fifth chapter. You have to prove the following theorem:

for any three functions *g*: $Y$$\rightarrow$ $E$, *h*: $E$ $\times$$\mathbb{N}$$\times$$Y$ $\rightarrow$ $E$ and *p*: $\mathbb{N}$$\times$$Y$ $\rightarrow$ $Y$, there is exactly one function *f*: $\mathbb{N}$$\times$$Y$ $\rightarrow$ $E$ which satisfies the identities *f* (0, y) = *g*(y) and *f*(*S*n, y) = *h*(*f*(n, *p*(n, y)), n, y) [where function *S* is the natural successor function].

Moschovakis gives a hint for the proof: define recursively a function *F*: $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$$\times$($\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $Y$) [where ($\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $Y$) represents the function space i.e. the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $Y$]; then the candidate for proving the theorem can be defined as *f*(n, y) = Second(*F*(n))(y) [the term 'Second' stands for the projection function of arity 2 whose value is the second component of its argument]. But I'm pretty sure that there is a typographical error in it because if *F* is defined in that way, the argument of the function obtained by composing the projection and *F* cannot be an element of $Y$ and it doesn't produce a value in $E$. So, any idea of the solution?

Comment: (I presume you mean 'a typographical error'; since _type_ is a technical term in very closely related topics, I've taken the liberty of changing the term to avoid confusion.  If you actually mean that there's an error in the typing - e.g., in the signature of one of the functions - please feel free to correct it back.)

Comment: No, I meant a typographical error, so I agree with your change.

Comment: What do you think the error is, exactly?

Comment: I edited the question including the hint given by Moschovakis. So I explained there why I think there is an error. But, beyond the error, the problem is the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the following is what Moschovakis had in mind. By recursion we first define a sequence of functions from $Y$ to $E$:

$f_0$ is just $g$

$f_{n+1}$ is the function which takes value $h(f_n(p(n, y)),n, y)$ for each $y\in Y$

Our required function is then defined by $f(n, y) = f_n(y)$, and uniqueness can be proved by induction in the usual way.

Comment: But $h$ depends on $\mathbb{N}$, too. Can we define another sequence before?

Comment: In what sense does $h$ depend on $\mathbb{N}$? $g$, $h$, and $p$ are the functions we start with, right? So we can use them however we like in the recursive definition of the $f_n$'s.

Comment: You wrote $h(f_n(p(n, y)), y)$; this isn't correct, because $h$ has arity 3 and takes its second argument from $\mathbb{N}$. This is what I meant. That said, I'm not sure your sequence is well defined.

Comment: Oh, I see; thanks! I've fixed that now. What do you think is wrong with the definition of the $f_n$'s?

Comment: At this point in the theory you just have Dedekind's recursion theorem and recursion theorem with argument as parameter (plus versions with parameters of both, obviously). With only this basis I fear you can't define a sequence like that one. You've defined a sequence of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $(Y \rightarrow E)$, so you must justify this with recursion theorem; but this assures you that exists a unique solution to this scheme (in this case): $f(0) = g$, $f(Sn) = h(f(n))$ where $h$ is from $(Y \rightarrow E)$ to $(Y \rightarrow E)$.

Comment: So you might want to use the version with parameters. Right, but in this case the scheme for which the theorem already proved yields a unique solution is the following: $f(0, y) = g(y)$, $f(Sn, y) = h(f(n, y), n, y)$. The difference is clear: the parameter here isn't an argument for another function which yields us the parameter for the defined function; it's an argument itself. This is the difficulty with this problem.

Comment: @UmbertoCavasinni If there are assumptions about what resources can be used in the proof, then you might want to make that explicit in the question. What I gave you follows immediately from the recursion theorem as outlined here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem

Comment: They aren't proper restrictions: I said that for clearness. The theorem that you linked is what I called the Dedekind's recursion theorem. I cannot see what is the "$F$" in your definition, that's my problem with your solution.

Comment: Where $X$ is the set of pairs of the form $\langle x, n\rangle$ where $x$ is a function from $Y$ to $E$, $a$ is $\langle g, 0\rangle$, and $f(\langle x, n\rangle)$ is $\langle z, n+1\rangle$ where $z$ takes value $h(x(p(n, y)), n, y)$ for each $y\in Y$.

Comment: So you want to say that $z$ is defined as $z(y) = h(x(p(n, y)), n, y)$. But this is the problem: your goal is to justify the existence of this function and you haven't done yet.

Comment: Are you asking how I know that $z$ exists, given $\langle x, n\rangle$? This follows by separation on $Y\times E$. Literally, $z = \{\langle y, e\rangle\in Y\times E: e = h(x(p(n, y)), n, y)\}$.

Comment: No. I'm asking you why $f$ exists and satisies the identities required by the theorem, because $z$, which must serve you at the recursion step, doesn't solve the scheme of any recursion theorem that you have at hand.

Comment: Your definition of $z$ by separation is wrong because $n$ is free.

Comment: Again, I know by separation. This time by separation on $Y\to E \times Y \to E$. To be clear, I'm using $f$ now in the sense of the wiki article, not in the sense of my answer. Let $F$ be the function which results from my definitions of $X$, $a$, and $f$ in the comments above. Then the $f$ of my answer is defined as $f(n, y) = F(n)(y)$.

Comment: Separation can have free variables. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification

Comment: No. You can have parameters, but the free variable in the formula must be satisfied by the elements of the set. What set you just defined otherwise? You have defined another function, that depends on $n$ in the following sense: for every $n$ you have a different set.

Comment: I'm not following you, sorry. Let me know if you manage to solve the problem, though!